# How to make a JButton add text from one JTextArea to another JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to be able to type in text to the JTextArea 't1' and then press the JButton 'b1' which will add the text from 't1' to the JTextArea 't2'. I have some code already in the actionPerformed method but it doesn't seem to function and i'm not sure why. Theres no error message instead the code just does not function at all. In my code sample here I have only included the method that creates the button, JTextAreas and the action listener method. Sorry if I have not asked this question entirely correctly this is my first question on this platform.

```
private JTextArea t1, t2;
private JButton b1, b2;
private final static String newline = "\n";

UserInterface()
{
    t1 = new JTextArea();
    t1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15)));
    t1.setLineWrap(true);
    t1.setBounds(470, 25, 280, 330);
    t2 = new JTextArea("Enter Addresses Here");
    t2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border2, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15)));
    t2.setLineWrap(true);
    
    b1 = new JButton("Click");
    b1.setBackground(Color.decode("#95edc5"));
    b1.setBorderPainted(false);
    b1.setOpaque(true);
    b1.setText("View Addresses");
    b1.setForeground(Color.decode("#2f4d3f"));
    b1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b1.setBounds(470, 395, 280, 63);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String text = t2.getText();
    
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Click"))
    {
        t1.append(text + newline);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take of the line:
**b1.setText("View Addresses")**
as it is now the **buttonName**, but not **Click**, because of the **actionCommand** event
equality you're checking for

Or otherwise, this approach should solve your problem

```
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
       String text = t2.getText();

       if (e.getSource() == b1)
       {
         t1.append(text +  newline);
       }
   }
```